# Nginx and Django download *.mp3 file

Tags: django, nginx, download

I have a Django project which downloads files, currently its hosted on Linux VPS with Nginx serving the entire project.

I am getting an error when I try to download a file on this URL `http://example.net/downloader/VYOjWnS4cMY/myfile.mp3`

This is the error that Nginx is logging when I try to download a file.

```
2018/05/16 17:22:02 [error] 30075#30075: *3 open() "/var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/myfile.mp3/downloader/VYOjWnS4cMY/myfile.mp3" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 41.75.172.141, server: 173.212.212.165, request: "GET /downloader/VYOjWnS4cMY/myfile.mp3 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

And lastly, this is my Django view method which handles download functionality.

```
def download(request, youtube_id, filename):

"""
Serves the audio file.
"""
filepath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
file_exists = os.path.exists(filepath)

if settings.DEBUG:
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file_data:
        response = HttpResponse(file_data.read(),
                                content_type='audio/mpeg')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(
        smart_str(filename))
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    return response
else:
    # Have Nginx serve the file in production.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                                                smart_str(filename))
    return response

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

Below is my `nginx` configuration

```
 server {
     server_name example.com;

     location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

     location /static/ {
        root /var/www/html/project_name/app_name;
    }
     location ~ ^.*/(?P<request_basename>[^/]+\.(mp3))$ {
        root /var/www/html/project_name/app_name/media/$request_basename/; 
      }
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: What does your nginx.conf look like?

Comment: Also what is your `settings.MEDIA_URL`?

Comment: @rtindru, I have included my nginx conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way your nginx is configured, the `root` in your location block should point to the [root directory](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root), from where the entire relative paths are matched.

I am assuming the actual file is inside this directory structure:
`/var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/downloader/VYOjWnS4cMY/myfile.mp3`?

If that is the case; change your nginx location block to:

```
 location ~ ^.*/(?P<request_basename>[^/]+\.(mp3))$ {
    root /var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media; 
  }
```

This would look for the file in the path I mentioned above

#### Update 1:

First off, it looks like your Nginx is hijacking the request well before it reaches Django - just wanted to let you know that the path you have setup will match and Nginx will be serving all your `*.mp3` URIs. Seeing as you have Django code to handle this, you might want to think about expected behavior here.

Secondly, after understanding the issue better from your comments, it's clear to me that the problem is again with the Nginx code block.

You mentioned in the comments that the file is located at `/var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/myfile.mp3`,

Hence, what you seem to be suggesting is that any `*.mp3` file, regardless of the request URI path, will be served from the `/media` directory  - (which if true, I fear is not good scalable design).

In that case, what you need to do is rewrite the URI at Nginx and then serve the file.

```
 location ~ ^.*/(?P<request_basename>[^/]+\.(mp3))$ {
    rewrite ^.*/(?P<request_basename>[^/]+\.(mp3))$ /$request_basename break;
    root /var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media; 
  }
```

For clarity: this rewrite block takes any URL that has a `.mp3` in it and rewrites it so that the file is served directly from the root directory. **All relative paths are lost**

Examples:

example.net/downloader/VYOjWnS4cMY/myfile.mp3 -> `/var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/myfile.mp3`

example.net/downloader/VYOjWnS4cMY/some_other_path/more_relative_paths/myotherfile.mp3 -> `/var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/myotherfile.mp3`

I hope this gives you enough intuition to think about what you need to achieve.

Comment: No the actual file is located in `/var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/myfile.mp3`. but the download url is something like `example.com/downloader/aslk0331/myfile.mp3`

I have also adjusted everything as you pointed out but still am getting nginx error `File Not Found`.

Remember the download link is something like `example.com/downloader/a3020as/myfile.mp3`

So Nginx is appending  `/downloader/a3020as/myfile.mp3` to `root` directory whereby the actual mp3 file is located in media_root, `/var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/my_file.mp3`

Comment: Okay so as I understand it, your file is directly inside the `media` directory;
What is your `settings.MEDIA_URL`?

Comment: Here is my media url and media root
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.getenv('MEDIA_ROOT', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))`

Comment: Thank you this is what i have been looking for

Comment: Do you have any idea why in chrome it's just viewing the mp3 file instead of downloading but in firefox its downloading.

Comment: I think chrome defaults to playing the MP3 file. You need to set content disposition headers to force chrome to download I think.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure file is in path */var/www/html/project_folder/converter/media/myfile.mp3/downloader/VYOjWnS4cMY/myfile.mp3*, if yes then error could be related to django response.

As a good practice I would advice file download should be handled by NGINX directly, not by django. Webserver(s) NGINX/Apache are good at handling them.